# How to randomly offset rows in a Brick Texture?

Tags: materials, node-editor, drivers

I have a mapping node for a texture, and I want to change the X value's location based on B&W data. However, with mapping nodes, there is no input for X value location. Is there any way I could use a driver to do this, or do any of you have a different idea?

Picture explained:

I want to use the white noise texture I created (shown in viewport), to randomly offset a brick texture by shifting it on the X axis. However, there isn't a place to plug it in to the X location value of the mapping node. My question is how would I offset it? Is there a way to use drivers and retrieve the data and plug it in there? Or is there another way to do it?
[image]

Comment: Hello, have you tried using a Combine XYZ node and plugging it into the X ?

Comment: What would I plug into the X, and what would I plug the XYZ node into? I was trying different combinations, but nothing was working.

Comment: plug the white noise fac into the x input of the combine xyz then the output of the combine xyz into the location input of the mapping node (you might have to try Y or Z depending on the roation of your object)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, this helped so much.